# I am trying to batch create multiple text files in subfolders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am creating .txt files with a list of the file names within a given subfolder. I have around 100 subfolders within each of the 18 main folders, so I would like batch create the .txt files to save time if possible. 
For each subfolder, I am using the following code

```
dir /b > filenames.txt
```

Can I do this in larger batches from all subfolders within each main folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate recursively on all files in all subfolders of a given folder with **FOR /R**.
I believe the following code does the trick, assuming you want to parse D:\Test :

```
for /R "D:\Test" %I in (*) do @echo "%I" >> filenames.txt
```

**EDIT :**
The previous code outputs the full path to each file it finds, if you only want the filenames, use this code instead :

```
for /R "D:\Test" %I in (*) do @echo "%~nxI" >> filenames.txt
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP is asking, which is for a separate listing file in each directory.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Louis! And then thanks for clarifying, David! I adjusted the code slightly and the outcomes works the same for what I need. I did :    for /R %I in (*) do @echo "%~nxI" >> filenames.txt